# Electric Flux Formula

Tags: electrostatics, electric-fields

I’m struggling to understand how to calculate the electric flux of an electric field, E,  that creates an angle to a area vector A if the formula for electric flux is given by φ=∫Ε•dΑ , the dot product says the angle between E & A should either be 0 or 90)
I have seen the formula: φ = ΕΑcosθ but how do you get to it from φ=  ∫Ε•dΑ

Comment: See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dot_product#Geometric_definition)... I think you're missing some background on dot products

Comment: The dot product between two vectors, $E\cdot n $ is equivalent to $|E||n| \cos{\theta}$.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a diagram showing a part of a surface with an electric field passing through it.

[image]

To evaluate the flux you need the component of the electric field $E_\perp$which is perpendicular to the surface element of area $dA$ which is $E\cos \theta$ to give the flux $E \cos \theta \,dA $.

Another way of writing that is as a dot product $\vec E \cdot d\vec A$